# How to disable Auto re-sizing of JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

Hye I'm working on a Java J2SE (Test,just for knowledge) app. Here What I'm doing is that I wan to add 5  sub panels to a main panel. Then assign them different colors to them after that I have to assign JLabel with images of colorful boxes to them. Just by using Random class I have to randomly set visible the JLabels with images in the sub panels.

---

**The Problem!**
The problem is that the sub panels will automatically re sized whenever i add a JLabel with an image in them. How can I overcome this? I have searched a lot but failed to get to know about how to solve this problem!

**What I have been trying!** I have using different Layout manager but not success!

**My Code**

```
      import java.util.Random;
      import java.util.logging.Level;
      import java.util.logging.Logger;
      import javax.swing.JLabel;



     public class PanelMovement extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public PanelMovement() {
        initComponents();
        Thread t=new Thread(new RunThread());
        t.start();
        a.setVisible(false);
        b.setVisible(false);
        c.setVisible(false);
        d.setVisible(false);
        e.setVisible(false);
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        mainpanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        green = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        a = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        blue = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        b = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        black = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        c = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        white = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        d = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        yellow = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        e = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        mainpanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        green.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 0));
        green.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(97, 122));

        a.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/2.png"))); // NOI18N
        a.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                aMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout greenLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(green);
        green.setLayout(greenLayout);
        greenLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            greenLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(greenLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(a)
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        greenLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            greenLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(greenLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(a)
                .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        blue.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));

        b.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/5.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        b.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                bMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout blueLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(blue);
        blue.setLayout(blueLayout);
        blueLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            blueLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(blueLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(b)
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        blueLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            blueLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(blueLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(b)
                .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        black.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        c.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        c.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/3.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        c.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                cMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout blackLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(black);
        black.setLayout(blackLayout);
        blackLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            blackLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(blackLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(c)
                .addContainerGap(11, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        blackLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            blackLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, blackLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(c)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        );

        white.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));

        d.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/1.png"))); // NOI18N
        d.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                dMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout whiteLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(white);
        white.setLayout(whiteLayout);
        whiteLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            whiteLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(whiteLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(d)
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        whiteLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            whiteLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, whiteLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(d)
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );

        yellow.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));

        e.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/4.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        e.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                eMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout yellowLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(yellow);
        yellow.setLayout(yellowLayout);
        yellowLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            yellowLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, yellowLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(e)
                .addGap(19, 19, 19))
        );
        yellowLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            yellowLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, yellowLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(e)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        );

        jLabel1.setText("Score=");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout mainpanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainpanel);
        mainpanel.setLayout(mainpanelLayout);
        mainpanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mainpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(mainpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(199, 199, 199)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(tt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, mainpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                .addComponent(green, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                .addComponent(blue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(black, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(white, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(yellow, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        mainpanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mainpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(mainpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(131, 131, 131)
                .addGroup(mainpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(yellow, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(black, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(blue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(green, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(white, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 115, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(mainpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(44, 44, 44))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(mainpanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(mainpanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
     int count=0;
    private void aMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
        count+=1;
        tt.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }                              

    private void bMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
        count+=1;
        tt.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }                              

    private void cMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
      count+=1;
        tt.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }                              

    private void dMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
     count+=1;
        tt.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }                              

    private void eMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
        count+=1;
        tt.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    }                              
    private class RunThread implements Runnable{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();



    public void run(){
        boolean flag=true;
            while(flag){
                int  RandomBox = randomGenerator.nextInt(5)+1;

                try{
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
      if(RandomBox==1){
         a.setVisible(true);
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                          a.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }


      }
      else if(RandomBox==2){
          b.setVisible(true);
          try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                          b.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
      }
      else if(RandomBox==3){
          c.setVisible(true);
          try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                          c.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
      }
      else if(RandomBox==4){
          d.setVisible(true);
          try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                          d.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
      }
      else if(RandomBox==5){
        e.setVisible(true);
        try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                          e.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
    }

    }
            }


}
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelMovement.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PanelMovement().setVisible(true);
                new PanelMovement().pack();
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel a;
    private javax.swing.JLabel b;
    private javax.swing.JPanel black;
    private javax.swing.JPanel blue;
    private javax.swing.JLabel c;
    private javax.swing.JLabel d;
    private javax.swing.JLabel e;
    private javax.swing.JPanel green;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainpanel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tt;
    private javax.swing.JPanel white;
    private javax.swing.JPanel yellow;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**The Screen Shots**

***Before adding a JLabel***
[image]
**after adding a jlabel(the real problem)**
[image]

Comment: Why to use labels at all? You could use simple graphics.

Comment: Why use netbeans to code such a simple GUI anyways? A simple `GridBagLayout` would work wonders!

Comment: @bran088
can you please explain? just give me hints about what type of graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was embracing for me to solve my own problem. I tried everything till my last option. I have found a solution that instead of using sub panels why not add the JLabels to the main panel and use the thread to randomly set visible them. This was great! My new Code is:

```
     import java.util.Random;
     import java.util.logging.Level;
     import java.util.logging.Logger;


    public class Panel extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Panel() {
        initComponents();
        a.setVisible(false);
        b.setVisible(false);
        c.setVisible(false);
        d.setVisible(false);
        e.setVisible(false);

        Thread t=new Thread(new RunThread());
        t.start();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        b = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        c = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        e = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        a = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        d = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/2.png"))); // NOI18N

        c.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/1.png"))); // NOI18N

        e.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/4.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        a.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/4.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        d.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/3.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(b))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(294, 294, 294)
                        .addComponent(c))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                        .addComponent(a)))
                .addContainerGap(283, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(e)
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(d)
                        .addGap(104, 104, 104))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(b)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addComponent(d)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(c)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(a)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(e)
                .addGap(121, 121, 121))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }                       
    private class RunThread implements Runnable{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();



    public void run(){
        int i;


       try{

           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                 boolean flag=true;
            while(flag){
                int  RandomBox = randomGenerator.nextInt(5)+1;

                try{
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
      if(RandomBox==1){
         a.setVisible(true);
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                          a.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }


      }
      else if(RandomBox==2){
          b.setVisible(true);
          try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                          b.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }
      }
      else if(RandomBox==3){
          c.setVisible(true);
          try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                          c.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }
      }
      else if(RandomBox==4){
          d.setVisible(true);
          try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                          d.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }
      }
      else if(RandomBox==5){
        e.setVisible(true);
        try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                          e.setVisible(false);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }
    }

    }

        }


       }catch(Exception e){

       }

    }
}
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Panel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel a;
    private javax.swing.JLabel b;
    private javax.swing.JLabel c;
    private javax.swing.JLabel d;
    private javax.swing.JLabel e;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

It will restrict the components to re sized automatically...Bingoo

Answer (score 0):

Would something like `.setResizable(false)` work? Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use null layout manager or AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: I have it but no resultssss dear